# Webelement finding issues

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Webelement finding issues in the mentioned below case

On the webpage https://pastebin.com/ it is required to select the option '10 Minutes' from the dropdown 'Paste Expiration:'

Here are the taken steps:

```
//Identification the Never option and clicking it the dropdown to show up
//This part of the code works
WebElement pasteExpiration = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='form_frame_left']//*[@title = 'Never']"));
pasteExpiration.click();

//Selecting the'10 Minute' option, this code is not identified by the WebDriver
WebElement pasteExpiration10Minutes = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#select2-paste_expire_date-q4-container"));
```

WebDriver does not see '10 Minute'option field, we tried to write our own xpaths, nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below lines:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(@id,'select2-paste_expire_date')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='10 Minutes']")).click();
```

It worked for me. I have checked on chrome browser.